# If statement in Reports

Tags: reporting, formula

I'm trying to create a formula field in report with following condition, but I'm only getting 1 otherwise 0 (if `A<10`) as a result.

```
IF(
AND(
Opportunity.A__c:SUM> 10,
Opportunity.B__c:SUM> 20),1,
IF(
AND(
Opportunity.A__c:SUM> 20,
Opportunity.B__c:SUM> 30),2,0))
```

Comment: Can you specify the rule just in English language what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rule you set up if `A > 10 and B > 20 return 1` otherwise fall into the next IF statement being if `A > 20 and B > 30 return 2` and if both of those fail then return 0. The problem with this is that if it is the second scenario and it should return 2. It will still be picked up by the first IF statement. Because if A is 25 and B is 35 both of those numbers are greater than 10 and 20. You need to flip the order that this is being read. Like the following:

```
IF(
AND(
Opportunity.A__c:SUM> 20,
Opportunity.B__c:SUM> 30),2,
IF(
AND(
Opportunity.A__c:SUM> 10,
Opportunity.B__c:SUM> 20),1,0))
```

This way if it is the higher number it will return 2, and if not it will check if it is going to return 1 and then finally if all else fails it will return 0. Hope this helps you.